# Is it possible to connect two "while" cycles to get the answer? Java

Tags: java, regex, file, while-loop, cycle

I want at first to read lines from the file, rewrite text to another file

```
File dir = new File("C:/Users/PC/workspace/uplo/");
```

The File I got:

```
   String source = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Output.txt";
```

The File I want to write to:

```
   String dest = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Final.txt";

   File fin = new File(source);
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));

   OutputStreamWriter fstream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest, true), "UTF-8");

   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

Cycle to rewrite content to the new Final.txt file:

```
   String aLine = null;
   while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

I want to put this cycle to remove duplicates from file, but unfortunately I have no idea how to do it...

```
   String regex = "\\b(\\w+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

   Matcher m = p.matcher(aLine);
   while (m.find()) {
        aLine = aLine.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
    }

   out.write(aLine);
   out.newLine();
   }

       in.close();
       out.close();
```

Could someone help me with this? I am doing my home work and i can't merge it together :)

For example I would like to rewrite text:

```
   Hello hello hello my name name Name is Arthur and I live in in Lithuania.
```

To:

```
   Hello my name is Arthur and I live in Lithuania.
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicates by line, or this also applies to duplicates between lines, e.g. `"Hello!\n"Hello!"`?

Comment: Quite honestly I don't know what is the problem. You seem to have it all there and it appears to work fine for me. Where exactly are you having trouble putting all this together?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo also and between lines

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo i am getting the same text as it was in original, program won't remove duplicates

Comment: I just tried your program and it works just fine for me. The regex might be improved a bit since it fails with certain words with apostrophes like "don't", but other than that it works fine for me.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo can you tell me what was you input and what output did u get?  Did you use txt files?

Comment: I just provided an answer. I did not use files, but I did use an input and output streams, so I works just the same.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo can you help me with removing words which are not in a row but in a whole text? for example hello, how are hello you? to: hello, how are you?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it worked fine for me. I would perhaps improve the regex a bit to include other words not accepted in the current implementation, e.g. words with apostrophes, like "don't", "won't", etc.

But that's probably not a big deal. I tried the following with success:

```
String regex = "\\b((\\w|\\p{Punct})+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))) {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String aLine;
        while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(aLine);
            while (m.find()) {
                aLine = aLine.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
            }
            out.write(aLine);
            out.newLine();
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I provide the input "Don't DON'T worry WoRRy, be BE happy HAPPY!" and I get back "Don't worry, be happy!"

I'm not sure if this example helps at all with your question, since it is not clear for me where exactly you're having trouble and your original code seems to be OK.

Comment: I know that regex is working fine, but trouble is that i am getting file with the same text as original, any regex :) so I don't know, where is the mistake. Both while loops are working fine, but it seems loop in loop not

Comment: I found a problem, it is not working with Lithuanian language :/ why?

Comment: As I said, I took your program and runnit verbatim and it works just fine for me. Are you sure you're checking the "final.txt"? Notice that your input file is actually called "Output.txt", which is very confusing. And the results of dedup are located in "Final.txt". I ran your program and the "Final.txt" looks just fine.

Comment: Oh I see! You'll need to use a unicode regex for that matter

Comment: Can you give a hand? :)

Comment: one more question, how could i remove all duplicate words, not only in a row

Comment: How about you change the regex to `"\\b(\\p{IsAlphabetic}+)(\\s+\\1\\b)+"`? That seem to work for me. This is just replacing the `\w` by `\p{IsAlphabetic}` which as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) does support all unicode characters.

Comment: thank you! it works, but can you tell me how to remove duplicates which are not in a row?  for example hello, how are hello you? to: hello, how are you?